# table with images refreshes on every update

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am attempting to create a table with a checkbox, an image, and an image title in each cell.

I created the table statically with no values in the cell items.

I then dynamically fill in each cell.

When I click a checkbox in the cell, the page flickers for the first 2 check boxes, then on the 3rd and subsequent clicks it repaints the whole table.

I added a RadScriptManager, but it appears to have had no effect.

I do nothing on the Page Load postback except load a few variables from the Session state.

This is part of my ASPX page.

```
    <asp:Table ID="tblItems" runat="server" GridLines="Both" Width="98%" >
    <asp:TableRow ID ="tr1" runat="server" Visible="false">
    <asp:TableCell ID="tcR1C1" runat="server">
    <asp:CheckBox ID="cbR1C1" runat="server" 
OnCheckedChanged="cb_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true" />
    <asp:Label ID="lblR1C1" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <asp:Image ID="imgR1C1" runat="server" Width="200px" Height="200px" />
    </asp:TableCell>
```

this is part of my initial load page

```
lbl.Text = lProducts.Products[iCurrentProduct].title;
img.ImageUrl = lProducts.Products[iCurrentProduct].image.src;
```

I am initially loading the object from an http://. Not sure if that is the issue. I could get each item locally as an image, then put it in the table, but I think the table should not be updating all the time - I thought that is what the RadScriptManager was supposed to do?

Comment: Typed win instead of web.  Changed tags

Comment: I think RadScriptManager is just a JavaScript bundler for ASP.NET. I don't think it changes the default behavior of `AutoPostBack="true"`, which is to reload the page when the checkbox is clicked.

Comment: Did you try wrapping it in a RadAjaxPanel?